# Understanding a Lang's proof of Sylow theorem (related to the class formula)

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

[image: al]

This proof comes from S. Lang's *Algebra Revised Third Edition*. Honestly 2/3 of this proof makes sense to me, except the application of class formula and the followings. My questions are:

1. Why do we have $(G:G_x)$ is divisible by $p$? Is it possible to deduce this simply from the fact that $(G:G_x)>1$?
2. Why $p$ divides the order of $Z$ because $p$ divides the order of $G$?

Appreciate in advance for anything helpful. It seems that I'm missing some critical details of the class formula. Feel free to point out anything wrong with me!

---

Edit 1: Some denotations.

> The set of elements $x \in G$ such that $xs=s$ is obviously a subgroup of $G$, called the **isotropy** group of $s$ in $G$, and denoted by $G_s$.

Moreover, Lang denoted the **orbit** of $s$ under $G$ by $Gs$.

Comment: What are the $G_x$s in this context?

Comment: @OlivierRoche I just added some denotations required. Feel free to check it out!

Comment: OK, now everything should be fine in my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Why do we have $(G:G_x)$ is divisible by $p$? Is it possible to deduce this simply from the fact that $(G:G_x)>1$?

$G_x$ is a subgroup of $G$. Since $(G:G_x)>1$, $G_x$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, so that we know that $p$ divides $(G : G_x)$. Equivalently, one could argue that $G_x = G \Leftrightarrow x \in Z$.

> 2. Why $p$ divides the order of $Z$ because $p$ divides the order of $G$?

Once 1. has been proved, you get that $\sum (G : G_x)$ is divisible by $p$. Since $(G : 1)$ is also divisible by $p$ and $0 \neq (Z : 1) = \sum (G : G_x) - (G : 1)$, this implies that $p$ also divides $(Z : 1)$.

Comment: Appreciate it since I think I learnt more than just understanding this proof! I should've tried to calm down and do more basic calculation.

Comment: @ZoeDesvl The way the arguments are stated in Lang's proof is confusing! I still don't understand where the fact that $(G : G_x) >1$ could be usefull...

Comment: I get it now : you need that the $G_x$s are **proper** subgroups.

Comment: Indeed, that's why "$(G:G_x)>1$ hence divisible by $p$". Another interesting fact, many proofs discussed $p | |Z|$ and $p \nmid |Z|$ separately, but Lang made it at one stroke.